# Why isn't jQuery emptying the div before the function is being applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following function to calculate the total price of a product:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function j_updateprice() {
    var p = 0;
    jQuery('.am-signup-form input[type=radio][id^=product]:checked, 
            .am-signup-form input[type=checkbox][id^=product]:checked')
    .each(function(i, v) {
      if (jQuery(v).attr('data-first_price')) {
        p += parseFloat(jQuery(v).attr('data-first_price'));
      }
    });
    jQuery('#j_price').text(p.toFixed(2));
  }

  jQuery('.am-signup-form input[type=radio][id^=product], 
          .am-signup-form input[type=checkbox][id^=product]')
  .change(function() {
     j_updateprice();
  });

  j_updateprice();
});
```

The problem is, when I click on the checkboxes/radio buttons of another div the price just keeps adding up (it shouldn't). So I thought of emptying the total (`#j_price`) before the `j_updateprice()` is being applied:

```
  jQuery('.am-signup-form input[type=radio][id^=product], 
          .am-signup-form input[type=checkbox][id^=product]')
  .change(function() {
    jQuery('#j_price').empty();
    j_updateprice();
  });
```

But nothing happens. The price just keeps adding up. Why is that?

Live site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup

Comment: You need to subtract from the `p` variable when unchecking an item.

Comment: not related but I think `.data('first_price')` is preffered over `.attr('data-first_price')`

Comment: @Joshua Coussard Sorry, I didn't understand well. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got your function wrong. I now think it is cause before the radio button in the unselected package is still selected.

Comment: @alexchenco jquery handles "data" attributes a "special" way. It's not really all that special, but to access the content of a data-attribute, you use `$(selector).data('attr-name')` ie: `jQuery(v).attr('data-first_price')` should be `jQuery(v).data('first_price')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider the checked elements within the selected panel, now you are considering all the checked items within the form which will include items in the previously selected panel also

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function j_updateprice() {
        var p = 0;
        jQuery('.am-signup-form .panel-expanded input[type=radio][id^=product]:checked, .am-signup-form .panel-expanded input[type=checkbox][id^=product]:checked').each(function (i, v) {
            if (jQuery(v).attr('data-first_price')) p += parseFloat(jQuery(v).attr('data-first_price'));
        });
        jQuery('#j_price').text(p.toFixed(2));
    }

    jQuery('.am-signup-form input[type=radio][id^=product], .am-signup-form input[type=checkbox][id^=product]').change(function () {
        j_updateprice();
    });

    j_updateprice();
});
```

Note: You will also have to call `j_updateprice` when the selected panel is changed

Comment: @Thanks for the answer! As for the note, isn't this line: `jQuery('.am-signup-form input[type=radio][id^=product], .am-signup-form input[type=checkbox][id^=product]')` doing exactly that?

Comment: I don't see that problem. The only one I have is that the default price (a radio button) doesn't show up in the total price when the page first loads.

Comment: @alexchenco it is selecting all the checked items within the form `am-signup-form`... but from the UI I guess you want to select only items within the selected `panel-login`

Comment: @alexchenco where is the default price checkbox located... does it have a separate id or class

Comment: Yes: `#product-7-8` it's a radio button. The one in the middle. It's selected by default.

Comment: @alexchenco that is because when the page is loaded the first panel does not have the class `panel-expanded`

Comment: @alexchenco I think when the page is loaded you need to assign that class to the first panel since you are selecting an element from that by default